# Ruby exits with exit code 1 responding to TERM if running without shell

Tags: ruby, docker, signals, exit, exit-code

If Ruby receives the TERM signal, it usually exits with the exit code 143, which according to [this source](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html) indicates the process successfully responded to that signal. But if I make the script run without a shell, the exit code is 1.

With shell:

```
> cat Dockerfile 
FROM ruby:alpine
CMD ruby -e "Process.kill('TERM', Process.pid)" # <- shell form

> docker build -t term_shell . > /dev/null
> docker run term_shell
Terminated

> echo $?
143
```

Without shell:

```
> cat Dockerfile
FROM ruby:alpine
CMD ["ruby", "-e", "Process.kill('TERM', Process.pid)"] # <- exec form

> docker build -t term_exec . > /dev/null
> docker run term_exec

> echo $?
1
```

But if I exit myself with 143, the exit code is as expected:

```
> cat Dockerfile
FROM ruby:alpine
CMD ["ruby", "-e", "exit(143)"] # <- exec form

> docker build -t exit_exec . > /dev/null
> docker run exit_exec

> echo $?
143
```

Why is that? Does the exit code when ruby receives TERM comes not from Ruby, but the shell?

Comment: What are `term_shell` and `term_exit`?

Comment: The docker images build with the Dockerfile above the `docker run` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exit code of your second example is `1` because the call `Process.kill('TERM', Process.pid)` failed. `ruby -e` exited because of this failure, and the status code in that case is `1`.

- With `CMD ruby -e "Process.kill('TERM', Process.pid)"`, docker executes the given command in a shell. In a running container, it means that the root process with pid 1 will be `/bin/sh -c`, and the `ruby -e` command will be executed in a child process with another pid (for example 6).
- With `CMD ["ruby", "-e", "Process.kill('TERM', Process.pid)"]`, docker executes directly `ruby -e` as the root process with pid 1.

The PID 1 on Linux behaves differently than the normal ones. From [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#foreground):

> **Note:** A process running as PID 1 inside a container is treated specially by Linux: it ignores any signal with the default action. So, the process will not terminate on SIGINT or SIGTERM unless it is coded to do so.

So in your case, the `TERM` signal won't be sent to you process.

You can find more information on PID 1 behavior on this article:
https://hackernoon.com/my-process-became-pid-1-and-now-signals-behave-strangely-b05c52cc551c

Comment: Thanks to your link I realized that we want our containers to run with the `--init` option, which runs [tini](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#specify-an-init-process). The ECS option is called `"linuxParameters": {"initProcessEnabled": true}`